# How to select a ContentControl by mousedown and remove it by del key

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application with a canvas in it

```
<Canvas x:Name="DesignerCanvas" Grid.ColumnSpan="9" 
        Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0.013,10,0.027,0" >

</Canvas>
```

Through background code I am adding a number of contentcontrol items

```
ContentControl myContentControl = new ContentControl();            
myContentControl.Content = ACimage;
myContentControl.MouseLeftButtonDown += MyContentControl_MouseLeftButtonDown;            
DesignerCanvas.Children.Add(myContentControl);
```

And now I am trying to be able to:

1. Select ContentControl using mouse clicking

   `private void MyContentControl_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
       {
           ContentControl myContentControl = sender as ContentControl;
           myContentControl.Focus();
           myContentControl.SetValue(Selector.IsSelectedProperty, true);
       }`

   For some reason clicking doesn't fire the MyContentControl_MouseLeftButtonDown event.  Any ideas?

   2. Remove ContentControl using delete key from keyboard.

Could someone point a direction please?

Thank you very much.

Comment: add an inputbinding on myContentControl, then set focusable to true...once you click on it and press delete it would fire whatever method you used chose as the inputbinding method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for **1)** what you can do is add a `MouseLeftButtonDown` event handler like this :

```
myContentControl.MouseLeftButtonDown += MyContentControl_MouseLeftButtonDown;

private void MyContentControl_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    myContentControl.Focus();
    //Do what you want when the ContentControl is clicked.
}
```

In the event you can focus on the ContentControl and then do what you need.

For the **2)** you can use a `KeyDown` event on the ContentControl like this :

```
myContentControl.KeyDown += MyContentControl_KeyDown;

private void MyContentControl_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
    {
        //Do what you need.
    }
}
```

And in it you check if the key pressed is the Delete button and then you can do what you need.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I am quite new into the WPF/C# area.  Just one more thing, what events should I put into the canvas to active the selection of the ContentControl?  Thank you again?

Comment: You don't need to put anything on the canvas if you just add those two events in your code it should work. That's what the mouseLeftButtonDown does @khuang.

Comment: What the mouseLeftButtonDown event does is when someone will left click on the contentControl the event will call the associated function and in there you can do what you need @khuang.

Comment: Not sure why, but clicking on the contentcontrol doesn't trigger the firing of the MyContentControl_MouseLeftButtonDown event. See my updated post.

Comment: You don't have to recreate your myContentControl just put in as a global variable in your class so you can access it in any method @khuang